# React-Table get reference to rows in parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a react table component inside a component. The data for the table is taken from the redux store. I have a button to export the data to excel in the parent component and need to access the current filtered, sorted or grouped rows in the child react table component to export.

```
    const App = () => {

        const columns = React.useMemo(
            () => [
              {
                Header: 'ID',
                accessor: 'id',
              }, etc...
            ],[]);

        const myData = useSelector((state) => state.myData.myData);
        const data = React.useMemo(() => myData, [myData]);           

        const [rowsToExport, setRowsToExport] = useState([]);
        <CSVLink filename='table.csv' data={tableInstance.current.rows}>
            <button>Export</button>
        </CSVLink>
        
        return <Table columns={columns} data={data} ref={tableInstance} />
    }

    const Table =  React.forwardRef(({columns, data}, ref) => {
        const instance = useTable({columns, data});
        React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => instance);
    })
```

I have a reference to my table instance but on page load the CSVLink fails due to the reference to the table instance being null. I am using react-csv. How can I have my CSV link in the parent component and populate it with the latest rows from my table instance.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: No I just moved my csv link component inside my table component. Maybe you could check for value in the attribute.. like <CSVLink … data={tableInstance ? tableInstance.current.rows : [] />